# JSON parsing throws error for nil while payload has no null values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby-on-rails-4

I see this rather strange issue building my first rails 4 demo app, I have the POST request working through angular, however parsing it on the controller throws the error

```
Started POST "/home/contact" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-07-21 18:40:21 +0530
Processing by HomeController#contact as JSON
  Parameters: {"name"=>"Gabbar Singh", "email"=>"gabbar@rampur.in", "phone"=>"9820420420", "message"=>"kitne aadmi thein", "captcha"=>"03AHJ_VuvKsc5W9IrGKKnitvFp8niuxL2cnpIpJ2WgGXPkQFYVXBe4KKwfcLtVhrx3Juos-R36WcYGScXbJgA9ZLjoznN7ABvjnHlNQ5r5z25-jCs7BKJBf14ITvCqVqYRoU4Je2c7EJXa7K3IjPmNXeWvUosYbLsoGAtnlH17ScIM-MLrm9iDBAJqTO0xiOY4yYI7rYSgfcXcZg7DGLioni8XEelTqgjrlEoK21ORwstV8i90zRfqTmQExs8TjcYFZKzTD4oHqBbsXQCA4GMvrMRiWK5OmzXvauopthhijUDCDJqtg-cWGGuMCOb6dPNkqXW7oEMVCBo-U_e0Nw1dpXh0Goui8pgqvseadEG120d3kVZcke8WcmnIKdi2_VkUxhppOYnXjnAh"}
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 2ms

TypeError (no implicit conversion of nil into String):
  app/controllers/home_controller.rb:9:in `contact'
```

the `ContactRequest` object is as follows

```
class ContactRequest
    include ActiveModel::Model

    attr_accessor :name, :email, :phone, :message, :captcha

    validates :name, presence: true,length: {in:2..255}
    validates :email, presence: true, length: {in:6..255}
    validates :message, presence: true
    validates :phone, presence: true
    validates :captcha, presence: true
end
```

And the angular snippet posting this data is

```
        var post_data = {  //prepare payload for request
            'name':$scope.contact.name,
            'email':$scope.contact.email,
            'phone':$scope.contact.phone,
            'message':$scope.contact.message,
            'captcha':$scope.response  //send g-captcha-reponse to our server
        }

        $http.post(
            'home/contact',post_data
        ).success(function(response){
            console.log(response);
            //flush form data
            $scope.contact = {};
            if(response.error === 0){
                $scope.messages = "Thanks!" + $scope.contact.name + "for your request! We will get back to you shortly"
            }else{
                $scope.messages = "We are sorry but your request was not processed, please try again."
            }
        })
```

Controller where I get error

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController

  wrap_parameters false

  def index
  end

  def contact
    @contactReq = HomeHelper::ContactRequest.new(JSON.parse(params[:json]))

    logger.debug "ContactRequest: #{@contactReq.attributes.inspect}"

  end
end
```

I don't any nil or blank field for that matter in the logs nor in the form POST request payload in firebug

```
{
 "name":"Gabbar Singh",
 "email":"gabbar@rampur.in",
 "phone":"9820420420",
 "message":"kitne aadmi thein",
 "captcha":"03AHJ_VuvKsc5W9IrGKKnitvFp8niuxL2cnpIpJ2WgGXPkQFYVXBe4KKwfcLtVhrx3Juos-R36WcYGScXbJgA9ZL
joznN7ABvjnHlNQ5r5z25-jCs7BKJBf14ITvCqVqYRoU4Je2c7EJXa7K3IjPmNXeWvUosYbLsoGAtnlH17ScIM-MLrm9iDBAJqTO
0xiOY4yYI7rYSgfcXcZg7DGLioni8XEelTqgjrlEoK21ORwstV8i90zRfqTmQExs8TjcYFZKzTD4oHqBbsXQCA4GMvrMRiWK5Omz
XvauopthhijUDCDJqtg-cWGGuMCOb6dPNkqXW7oEMVCBo-U_e0Nw1dpXh0Goui8pgqvseadEG120d3kVZcke8WcmnIKdi2_VkUxhppOYnXjnAh"
}
```

Comment: show what is in the line #9 ?

Comment: doesn't allow me show lined numbers in any way, but the error is in this line `@contactReq = HomeHelper::ContactRequest.new(JSON.parse(params[:json]))` which I changed to `@contactReq = HomeHelper::ContactRequest.new(params)` based on suggestion by @maxd, but, to no effect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have `:json` parameter in `params` hash:

```
@contactReq = HomeHelper::ContactRequest.new(JSON.parse(params[:json]))
```

Look at your log above (near Parameters:)

I think you want to pass `params` to constructor like this:

```
@contactReq = HomeHelper::ContactRequest.new(params)
```

Comment: then I get `Started POST "/home/contact" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-07-21 19:14:45 +0530
Processing by HomeController#contact as JSON
 ...
NoMethodError (undefined method controller=' for #<HomeHelper::ContactRequest:0x007f905c06a4c0>):
  app/controllers/home_controller.rb:11:in 'new'
  app/controllers/home_controller.rb:11:in 'contact'`

Comment: essentially, I want to parse the JSON into an instance of `ContactRequest` class